# Create a pull request using Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

I'm using Bitbucket as a git management repository solution, and I want automatically create PRs, when my feature branches builds are successful.

So, is there any way to set this up with a Jenkinsfile?

Comment: Did you try something by yourself? You probably want to use the [Bitbucket API](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories)

Comment: @MichaelKemmerzell I hoped, that someone already did something like this and could provide an example, which I could reuse, and yes I will use bitbucket rest api to do it.

Comment: What about this? https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Creating-a-pull-request-via-API/qaq-p/123913 simply check out Google I think.